# "prisma generate" moves generated package outside of working directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I have a setup where I want to share a Prisma schema file between different `node` packages within a mono-repo.
The schema has multiple but these models are not exported to the client. The reason is because the local client is not actually updated when running `prisma generate --schema=...`. It updates another instance of the client, as can be seen in the output of the command:

```
$ npx prisma generate --schema=./../shared/prisma/prisma/schema.prisma
Prisma schema loaded from ../shared/prisma/prisma/schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client (3.12.0 | library) to ./../shared/prisma/node_modules/@prisma/client in 199ms
You can now start using Prisma Client in your code. Reference: https://pris.ly/d/client

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

Done in 2.66s.
```

In the local package directly under `node_modules` the types are nonsensical:

```js
export declare const PrismaClient: any
...
export declare type PrismaClient = any
export declare const dmmf: any
export declare type dmmf = any
...
```

How do I make sure that the local copy of the client is updated? Is there something wrong in the way I approach this (is there a better way to share a Prisma schema between packages)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your generator object from your schema. prisma file?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with prisma, at the moment. Prisma will generate the client in whatever project directory that the schema file resides. I also need to generate the client in a different directory than, but the only solution I have found is to copy the schema file into my project before doing `prisma generate`.